# React-Native : Any Changes Into react-native Libraries effects my app build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

Am new into react-native i have  bit problems.

1:If i make any changes into my react-native library such as a library called **react-native-viewpager** and i have done some customize changes and build the **sample.apk** so after build do will i get my customize changes or i will get default changes of **react-native-viewpager**.

2:In ios tabbar does every tabbar maintain its own stack as below.

homeTabbar => [Page_1, Page_2, Page_3 ]

profileTabbar => [Page_4, Page_2, Page_4]

if not then what i can do to achieve the above task.

I know its maintain only one array with all routes eg:

this.navigator.state.routeStack[Page_1,Page_2,Page_3,Page_4,Page_2,Page_4];

But i want to maintain every routes history according to tab once user reaches to homeTabbar=> [Page_1] if user swipe back with gesture user has to be on homeTabbar=> [Page_1] considering Page_1 as homepage for homeTabbar even its has many routes in this.navigator.state.routeStack;

Answer (score 0):

1st: Yes it does. But the reflection of the changes made depends upon wether you bundle JS before making the apk or not. Ofcourse JS bundling is necessary for building the app. So apparently it does.

Pro tip: Once you make changes in your node modules, make sure you keep them saved because you might lose it while installing new modules. So better fork the original library, keep your changes in your version of the library and use your git library version against the library in package.json. It will ensure that you not lose your changes and might also help the open source community.

2nd: Have you considered using `react-navigation` ? You should use it as you can use respective stacks for each of your tabs.